# ActiveStorage Analyzer job latency too high

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activestorage

I use ActiveJob, backed by Sidekiq. In the sidekiq web UI, I could see a large number of jobs enqueued to the `active_storage_analysis` queue, but the latency is very high and I don't see these jobs being cleared. As a result, Redis storage is occupied and can't be free. Do you know why is that? Did I config anything wrong that stops them from running?

[sidekiq UI with 8001 jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8dGh.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem, because I didn't define the queue in sidekiq.yml, so simply add to sidekiq.yml file the two queues:

```
---
:concurrency: 2
:queues:
  - critical
  - default
  - mailers
  - action_mailbox_routing
  - action_mailbox_incineration
  - low
  - active_storage_analysis
  - active_storage_purge
```